# Handling admin access to a Google Cloud Platform Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've got an email from Google; they said that I'm listed as an admin of the following project: `s~stable-furnace-358`.

Their goal is to make it easier for Google Cloud Platform customers to find and understand Terms of Service, Deprecation Policy and Service Level Agreements, covering all current and future Cloud Platform products and services:

> The Google Cloud Platform team would like to make sure you are aware of some changes we've recently made to the Google App Engine Terms of Service (ToS) as well as how and where we communicate Deprecation Policy and Service Level Agreement (SLA) information to our users.

My question is: how do I handle this project? And where i can find the tutorials?
Am I going to be charged for participation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you did not create a project on Google Cloud Platform in the past, this means that someone has added you as an admin of their project. If you did not expect this, it may mean that someone has mistyped the email of their friend or colleague and you were added instead. They may have since fixed it, so you might not see this project in your console.

As to your questions:

- **How to handle this project:** to see this project, visit the [Developer Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and you should see that project listed there, and you can explore it from there. Consider contacting the other admins on the project to let them know of their mistake if you did not expect to participate in this project.
- **Finding tutorials:** start on the [Google Cloud homepage](https://cloud.google.com/developers/) to get an overview of the platform, and see the [developers section](https://cloud.google.com/developers/)  section for tutorials and per-product guides.
- **Will you be charged:** some features require payment and some usage of Google Cloud Platform is free. You need to explicitly add your payment information to the project to enable being charged, so if you have not added your credit card, you will not be charged, but certain features will be unavailable.